# How to display pdf more than 2mb by using iframe? c# mvc and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, blob

I want to display my pdf in the web. Normally it's smaller than 5mb.

```
    <div>
        <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64, @base64String" style="width:100%; height:500px" />
    </div>
```

You can see this works pretty well for small pdfs, typically smaller than 2mb.

```
// this is what I did on my c# mvc controller.
var fData = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fname));

ViewData["base64String"] = fData ;
```

My approach is to create a blob type data and send it to views. Then I can use create url by using URL.createObjectURL(blob) and try to display it via iFrame. The code below is my approach but it's not working.

```
// for c# controller
            byte[] fileByte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            var temp = Convert.ToBase64String(fileByte);
            var res = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(temp));
            var pdf = string.Format("data:application/pdf;base64,{0}", fileContents[0]);
            ViewData["File"] = File(fileByte, "application/pdf");
            ViewData["Byte"] = fileByte;
            ViewData["Encoded"] = res;
            ViewData["Content"] = fileContents;
            ViewData["pdf"] = pdf;
```

```
// for my .cshtml

@{
    var base64String = ViewData["base64String"];
}

<iframe id="viwer">
</iframe>

<script>
    const blob = new Blob(['@base64String '], { type: 'application/pdf' });

    var obj_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

    const iframe = document.getElementById("viwer");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", obj_url);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(obj_url);
</script>
```

I tried several ways to encode the data from controller

```
            var temp = Convert.ToBase64String(fileByte);
            var res = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(temp));
            var pdf = string.Format("data:application/pdf;base64,{0}", fileContents[0]);
            ViewData["File"] = File(fileByte, "application/pdf");
            ViewData["Byte"] = fileByte;
            ViewData["Encoded"] = res;
            ViewData["Content"] = fileContents;
            ViewData["pdf"] = pdf;
```

I can't let it display the pdf even smaller than 2mb. I dont know where I did wrong.

I also tried this in javascript, it will return a error on html says the 'encStr' is not correctly encoded.

```
    const byteCharacters = atob('@encStr');
    const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
```

I want to solve it and make it work. I dont want to use external package. If it's the only way then I will use it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest simplifying your code a bit and following these steps:

1. Modify your C# controller to pass the byte array directly to the view.
2. In the .cshtml file, convert the byte array to a base64 string.
3. Create a blob object and set the iframe source to the object URL created from the blob

Modify your C# controller:

```cs
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
ViewData["FileBytes"] = fileBytes;
```

In your .cshtml file:

```
@{
    byte[] fileBytes = ViewData["FileBytes"] as byte[];
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
}
```

Create the blob and set the iframe source:

```html
<iframe id="viewer" style="width:100%; height:500px"></iframe>

<script>
    const base64String = '@Html.Raw(base64String)';
    const byteArray = Uint8Array.from(atob(base64String), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
    const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });

    const viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
    const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    viewer.setAttribute('src', objectUrl);
    viewer.onload = () => URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
</script>
```

This should work for displaying PDF files larger than 2MB in an iframe. Make sure to remove any unnecessary code from your controller and .cshtml file. This approach avoids double encoding, which may have caused the issue in your original implementation.

Comment: You are my life saver! thanks!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what's this line doing?  const byteArray = Uint8Array.from(atob(base64String), c => c.charCodeAt(0));

Comment: That line decodes the base64 string into a binary string, and then converts it into a byte array (Uint8Array) by mapping each character in the binary string to its corresponding byte value. This byte array is later used to create a Blob object for the PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your replay and your patient. This line make sense now. I have another question about display .```const iframe = document.getElementById("viwer");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", objectUrl);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);``` I try to use this 3 line here to display the pdf but it doesn't work. I just want to know why we have to reload the page to make the pdf appear? I thought what we need to do is to add src link.

Comment: You need to include the attribute "id="viewer" in your iframe element. If its already on place, you can try to add the onload function:

`const viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob); viewer.setAttribute('src', objectUrl); viewer.onload = () => URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);`